Started a container with docker run using --latest tag. How to update it now?
A year ago I started the container with:
docker run --name my_gluetun --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -e VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER="private internet access" \
-e OPENVPN_USER=abc -e OPENVPN_PASSWORD=xyz \
-v gluetun:/gluetun \
-e SERVER_REGIONS="US West" qmcgaw/gluetun

I want to make sure it is the "most recent latest" image, and not the latest from a year ago. With docker compose I would have:
docker compose pull
docker compose up -d --remove-orphans
docker image prune -f

What is an equivalent procedure, making sure my volumes (data, config, etc..) remains?
Thank you in advance.

docker image pull qmcgaw/gluetun to pull the latest image. After that, you can remove the container and start a new one with the same run command. Your volumes will remain the same if that's what you meant by "data and config".

To update your Docker container to the latest image and ensure your configuration and data remain intact:
Pull the Latest Image
docker pull qmcgaw/gluetun

Ensure you remove the container after stopping it, but since you are using a named volume (gluetun:/gluetun), your data will be preserved.
docker stop my_gluetun
docker rm my_gluetun

Re-run your docker run command to create a new container using the updated image. This will reuse the existing named volume.
Finally, you can clean up any unused Docker images to free up space:
docker image prune -f

